# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on forum template using Flask. When I attempt creating a new thread in the browser using forms, SQLAlchemy throws an AttributeError. The problem showed up when I tried implementing a one-to-many relationship with Forum-to-Thread and a one-to-many relationship with Thread-to-User.

models.py

```
class User(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True, unique=True)
  password = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
  role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=ROLE_USER)

  posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Forum(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(128))
  description = db.Column(db.Text)

  threads = db.relationship('Thread', backref='forum', lazy='dynamic')

class Thread(db.Model):

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(128))
  author= db.Column(db.String(32))
  timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  forum_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('forum.id'))

  posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='thread', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  body = db.Column(db.Text)
  timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
  thread_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('thread.id'))
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

All the new posts/threads and handled within views.py

views.py

```
@app.route('/forum/id=<id>/submit', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def new_thread(id):
  form = ThreadForm()
  forum = Forum.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    thread = Thread(title=form.title.data,
                    author=g.user.username,
                    timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    db.session.add(thread)
    db.session.flush()
    post = Post(body=form.body.data,
                timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                thread=thread.id,
                author=g.user.id)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Post successful.')
    return redirect(url_for('forum_index', id=id))
  return render_template('forum/thread_submit.html', title=forum.title, form=form)
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

the problem is this:

```
post = Post(body=form.body.data,
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            thread=thread.id,
            author=g.user.id)
```

you want to work with ORM objects, not primary key columns:

```
post = Post(body=form.body.data,
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            thread=thread,
            author=g.user)
```

the error means that an integer is being interpreted as an ORM object.

Answer (score -1):

Backref, sends an object. A database object specifically.

You can edit your database manually via a database browser. However, on air, the SqlAlchemy manages with objects. The parameter of yours is an 'int' object but not what SqlAlchem expected.

I had the same issue and suffered and overcame.